# How can I vertically center two spans on either side of a div, relative to that div?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Right now, it basically looks like this:

```
_______________________________________
|                                     |
|             ___________             |
|             |         |             |
|      ______ |   div   | ______      |
|      |span| |         | |span|      |
|      |____| |_________| |____|      |
|_____________________________________|
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
_______________________________________
|                                     |
|             ___________             |
|      ______ |         | ______      |
|      |span| |   div   | |span|      |
|      |____| |         | |____|      |
|             |_________|             |
|_____________________________________|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flexbox** can do that https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/220/

**CSS**

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.content div, 
.content span {
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.content div {
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    padding: 0 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <span>Span 1</span>
    <div>Div </div>
    <span>Span 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This does align them correctly, but now they have a huge spacing in between each element. Also, they are at the center of the container div. Can I put it somewhere near the top of the div? Codecademy didn't teach me about flexbox, do you have a recommended site where I can learn about it?

Comment: Yes you can, just remove `justify-content: space-around;`  https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/221/ and pick any https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties, https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Alright, now how can I center those horizontally? text-align: center; isn't working with this

Comment: You will have to try different options to adjust it for your project but you can take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/223/

Comment: You just have to add vendor prefixes like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/224/

Answer (score 0):

Will need to see your code to answer this more specifically, but try something like this

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"> ... </div>
```

If you put the div and spans in a table then you can simply add valign="middle" to the TD.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use `display:tablecell` and then `vertical-align:middle` for your div. I am fairly new to html though, so I may be wrong.